# Is Mass Flow an Additive Property?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Mass ($m$) is an additive property in the sense that the total mass within a system can be simply determined by adding up the mass of each individual substance that's in it.

However, if two mass flows ($m/t$) of different liquids were to be mixed to form a single flow, would the resulting mass flow be equal to the sum of each individual mass flow?

Comment: I think that when you say "mass flow" you actually mean the mass flow *rate* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_flow_rate)

Comment: I know this is not the point in the question, however, isn't mass flow rate, not a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming that by "mass flow" you mean the [mass flow rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_flow_rate) $\dot m$)

Yes. Since mass is a conserved quantity, it obeys the [continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation) in the form

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \mathbf j =0$$

where $\rho$ is the mass density and $\mathbf j$ is the mass flux.

As a consequence, if two flows with mass flow rates $\dot m_1, \dot m_2$ mix in a single flow $\dot M$, you will have

$$\dot m_1 + \dot m_2 = \dot M$$

If this wasn't true, it would mean that some mass was lost or created during the mixing.